# AndroidImageSlider при загрузке фото E/Bitmap? createBitmap error!

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.
В своём приложении я использую [AndroidImageSlider GitHub](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/daimajia/slider/demo/MainActivity.java)

Вот его код:

```
    SliderLayout exPhoto = (SliderLayout) findViewById(R.id.ex_img);
    exPhoto.removeAllSliders();
    for (String url : object.getImages()) {
            try {
                Log.e("test", "load textSliderView");
                TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
                textSliderView
                        .image(url)
                        .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
                exPhoto.addSlider(textSliderView);
            }catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
                Log.e("test", "exception textSliderView");
            }
        }
    exPhoto.stopAutoCycle();
```

Вот ошибка:

> 05-11 15:41:08.855    5873-6125/ru.mabee.justme_android.app E/Bitmap﹕
>   createBitmap error! 05-11 15:41:09.335
>   5873-6126/ru.mabee.justme_android.app E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed
>   1674K, 18% free 53549K/64995K, paused 4ms+22ms 05-11 15:41:09.445
>   5873-5873/ru.mabee.justme_android.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:492)
>               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:360)
>               at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
>               at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
>               at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:542)
>               at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:315)
>               at com.squareup.picasso.ImageViewAction.error(ImageViewAction.java:61)
>               at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.deliverAction(Picasso.java:563)
>               at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.complete(Picasso.java:510)
>               at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$1.handleMessage(Picasso.java:117)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 05-11 15:41:09.686    5873-6124/ru.mabee.justme_android.app E/dalvikvm﹕
>   GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 395K, 17% free 54464K/64995K, paused 2ms+18ms 05-11
>   15:41:09.856    5873-6124/ru.mabee.justme_android.app E/dalvikvm﹕
>   GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 105K, 17% free 54358K/64995K, paused 170ms 05-11
>   15:41:09.856    5873-6124/ru.mabee.justme_android.app E/dalvikvm-heap﹕
>   Out of memory on a 983056-byte
>   allocation.ion.error(ImageViewAction.java:61)
>               at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.deliverAction(Picasso.java:563)
>               at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.complete(Picasso.java:510)
>               at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$1.handleMessage(Picasso.java:117)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 395K, 17% free 54464K/64995K, paused
>   2ms+18ms E/dalvikvm﹕ GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 105K, 17% free 54358K/64995K,
>   paused 170ms E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 983056-byte
>   allocation.

Не знаю что делать.

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError говорит о том, что изображение слишком большого размера, чтобы загрузить его напрямую - частая ошибка при работе с изображениями. У Picasso/Glide есть методы, позволяющие при загрузке оптимизировать размер изображения. Еще можно почитать тут: [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: Это понятно, но у нас вся работа с изображением заключается в этой строчке кода `.image(url)` мы передаём только ссылку на изображение, и `textSliderView` сама с ней работает.
Аналогично и с `Picasso`, по факту мы только передаём ссылку (мы можем, конечно, изменить там размер метадами `fit()` и `replace()`), но ошибки `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` там не будет